# Remove more than one character of a ArrayList with a Keylistener

Tags: java, arraylist, character

If I remove the last character of my character ArrayList, the ArrayList is not shorter than before removing a Character. So I can not remove more characters than one.

```
public static ArrayList<Character>  userLineInput;

if (e.getKeyChar() == '\b') {
    if (!userLineInput.isEmpty()) {
        userLineInput.remove(userLineInput.size()-1);
        }
}
```

Is there a easy way to remove more than one character?

Comment: It works if first condition is matched.

Comment: I already tried it but it wont't work.

Comment: If you are trying to remove the Characters in the UI make sure you are updating your UI model and not just the underlying data structure.

Comment: But if I add "System.out.println(userLineInput.toString());" at the end it only outputs userLineInput with max. one Character removed.

Comment: Ok, it also could be that another thing in my Java document blocks this.

Comment: Ohh, I see, you probably want while(!userLineInput.isEmpty()) {}

Comment: When you say `userLineInput.remove(userLineInput.size()-1);` it only removes one character. The last one. What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: I know the problem. I forgot a return after `if (!userLineInput.isEmpty()) {...}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems that you need to define something like :

```
while(keyIsPressed)
   if(thePressedKey == '\b'){
removeOneChar();
}
```

here is a quick solution that may help you :

```
public class RemoveChar extends KeyAdapter {
    public static ArrayList<Character> userLineInput;
    private boolean isPressed = false;
    private int pressedKey = 0;
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (isPressed)
                if (pressedKey == '\b')
                    removeLastChar();
        }
    });

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if (!isPressed) {
            pressedKey = e.getKeyCode();
            t.start();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        if (isPressed && e.getKeyCode() == pressedKey)
            isPressed = false;
    }

    public void removeLastChar() {
        userLineInput.remove(userLineInput.size() - 1);
    }
}
```